# AmbiguousTimeError related to a specific datetime (2020-11-01)

Tags: mysql, django, pytz

This is coming up in the context of a django project. All datetime objects are tz aware. One day the production server crashed with the follow error:

`pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: 2020-11-01 01:00:00`

The strange thing is that if I change this date manually in the database to almost anything else, the error goes away. Also, if I copy the problematic date into any other datetime field in the database, the same exception is thrown.

I have also tried to add this datetime to other records, and the same problem occurs with those records. Same applied to test and dev databases.

Any ideas?

I am using a mysql database.

UPDATE:
seems like this is an issue related to the [daylight savings switchover](https://github.com/floraison/et-orbi/issues/23).

Comment: Right, it's because you're using a timezone with DST. There are indeed ambiguous datetimes in such timezones. That's why it's always recommended to use an unambiguous timezone (`UTC` in particular) to represent canonical datetimes.

Comment: Great point -- thanks @kevin. So if I were to change over the timezone used by the project, I am guessing this would result in all the datetimes recorded in the database to now be incorrect, right?

Comment: There's not enough detail here to say. Is this a pre-existing legacy database? Django stores all datetimes in UTC regardless of the timezone setting.

Comment: @kevin, yes it is a legacy db. So changing the TIME_ZONE setting shouldn't impact how dates are recorded in the db? If so, then what is the meaning of this setting?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/). In essence it's the default value used for presenting datetimes to and interpreting datetimes from end users. Ideally you would convert your database to UTC, but I don't know enough about MySQL to know the best way to do that. The other option is to disable Django's time zone support with `USE_TZ = False`.